# Не могу понять, почему при запуске кода пишет "invalid syntax" ведь в коде нет опечаток

Tags: python, pygame

Не могу понять, почему при запуске кода пишет "invalid syntax" при этом ссылаясь на 45 (предпоследняя) строку (код из 45 строки: `pygame.quit()` ), ведь в коде нет опечаток.

Код:

```
import pygame

# создаем экран
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)).fill((white))

pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.set_caption("Random dice")




#цвета
aqua      = (  0, 255, 255)   # морская волна
black     = (  0,   0,   0)   # черный
blue      = (  0,   0, 255)   # синий
fuchsia   = (255,   0, 255)   # фуксия
gray      = (128, 128, 128)   # серый
green     = (  0, 128,   0)   # зеленый
lime      = (  0, 255,   0)   # цвет лайма
maroon    = (128,   0,   0)   # темно-бордовый
navy_blue = (  0,   0, 128)   # темно-синий
olive     = (128, 128,   0)   # оливковый
purple    = (128,   0, 128)   # фиолетовый
red       = (255,   0,   0)   # красный
silver    = (192, 192, 192)   # серебряный
teal      = (  0, 128, 128)   # зелено-голубой
white     = (255, 255, 255)   # белый
yellow    = (255, 255,   0)   # желтый


#print text
pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render('Hello world!', True, yellow, blue)
textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
textRectObj.center = (500, 400)

screen.fill(white)
screen.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj


#start loop
game_end = False

while not game_end:
    #game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_end = True
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Опечаток нет, есть недопечатки: `screen.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj` - скобку кто будет закрывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли закрыть скобку в конце этой строки:

```
screen.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj
```

Comment: @VanProBRO Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа ;)

Comment: Вопросы с опечатками принято закрывать с соответствующей причиной. Можно миллионом разных способов сделать опечатку, и каждое исправление не имеет никакой ценности для базы знаний.

Comment: @insolor https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56091075

Comment: И каким образом это сообщение в чате отменяет действие правил?

Comment: @insolor А где в правилах сказано, что я не имею права ответить на такой вопрос? ;)

Comment: @insolor Если вы про: <q>Не на все вопросы стоит отвечать. Уберегите себя от разочарования и не отвечайте на вопросы, которые</q>, то мне вспомнилась одна цитата. "Это приказ? Нет, это совет." (Закон есть закон).